# Brainwave audio recordings and beta waves: how do they affect positivity?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology

I know a little bit about negative and positive energies of human bodies and how it all works.
Recently, on Facebook, I saw an ad promoting some sort of audio recording and that it has something to do with the **beta waves**.

They claimed,

> Listen to the 15-minute demo once per day, every day, for at least the next seven days. You'll soon start noticing the subtle, positive differences, if you haven't already.

So I downloaded that audio clip (15 minutes long), expecting it to be something relaxing.

As it turned out, it was the sounds of waterfalls, leaves and trees for the whole 15 minutes.

Even though I like this 15 minute sound clip, I wonder how this could help in improving positivity if we listen to it regularly?

This is the whole text that I received as e-mail after signing up for the AD,

> Some people report feeling much more relaxed. Others feel that time speeds up -- or slows down. Almost everyone reports that it's an enjoyable experience! And what about the sounds of rustling leaves and trickling waterfalls? We travelled to Derbyshire, in the heart of rural England, and spent a month capturing the natural sounds used in the BrainEv program. But what you might not realize is...There's actually much, much more going on in the background! You see, the sounds of the streams and trees are really just a rich "sound mask" for the powerful brainwave recordings that are playing in the background. Let me explain a little more...Your brain cells all talk to each other using tiny little electrical signals. With billions of these brain cells talking at once, that's a pretty significant amount of electrical activity -- and can be detected with an EEG machine. This electrical activity is what we call a brainwave. And the brainwave frequencies change, depending on what state you're in. When you're happy, when you're focused, when you're asleep -- your brainwaves all have very specific frequencies. And here's the exciting part. Using a science known as 'brainwave entrainment', we can now create special brainwave audio recordings, which play specific frequencies to the brain. The brain copies these frequencies, and effectively RECREATES the original brainwave pattern. That means we can recreate brainwave patterns that help you relax and release stress... that activate your intelligence... that improve your mood... that help you feel more focused during the day. Not only that, but by accessing these peak performance states on a daily basis (as with the BrainEv program), they'll start becoming second nature -- and available to you literally on-demand.

Comment: Voted to close because it is a "state of binaural beats research" question, answered here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8371/is-there-scientific-evidence-on-the-benefits-of-binaural-beats