# What neurophysiological mechanisms are typically associated with distraction?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience

I've been looking into focus aids and I've come across [some music](https://www.focusatwill.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/White-Paper-on-Focus@Will-Reading-Research.pdf) which markets itself as entertaining your "limbic system". Although it's been asked before [how music can affect mental states](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1882/is-there-psychoactive-music), I'm trying to figure the accuracy of the claim that the "limbic system" is the source of distraction.

Are the neurophysiological mechanisms associated with distraction really as distributed as the "limbic system"? I typically associate the salience managers of the brain to be found in the basal-ganglia and thalamus, but I don't have any proof for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do some students find it difficult to focus on study when at home?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/13939/why-do-some-students-find-it-difficult-to-focus-on-study-when-at-home)

Comment: I touched this question in another post. I marked this as a duplicate so that the answer is linked ;)